# Time out Exception in C#.net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
 public DataTable GetDailycardReport(DailyReportPL dailyreportpl)
    {
        DataTable dtGetDailycardReport = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] arParams = new SqlParameter[2];

            arParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@farmername", typeof(string));
            arParams[0].Value = dailyreportpl.farmername;

            arParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@batchno", typeof(int));
            arParams[1].Value = dailyreportpl.batchno;

            dtGetDailycardReport.Load(SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connection.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "k_DailyCardreport", arParams));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //DBExceptionPublisher exc = new DBExceptionPublisher();
            //exc.Publish(ex);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return dtGetDailycardReport;

    }
```

**Exception ::**

```
"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of 
    the operation or  the   server is not responding."
```

When I pass parameters to stored procedure its caught an exception and displaying above
message".How to increase command timeout to 200 in `webconfig` file. I searched in google
but no optimized result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set it on your command object also

```
   cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
```

Specify your time in seconds.

Comment: *or the server is not responding* could technically be a `connection timeout` issue.

Comment: @BobbyDigital *The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation* could technically be a `CommandTimeout` issue.

Answer (score 6):

It can be set in the connectionstring, like the following where it is set to 200 seconds.

> "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;**Connection Timeout=200**"

[**Source**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)